# Using handlebars.js and sheetrock.js but not working

Tags: google-sheets, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars.js and sheetrock.js . The funny thing is I have used the same script over and over but this time it will not pull the cells information from the spreadsheet. I have made sure the spreadsheet is public and it can be [found here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17kW3grN5rrKMnaA-5oS77EZr2Jmfu43oSPXBZKd8BAw/edit#gid=0). I have went over and over the script now for a week. I am not getting any kind of error code in the console so not sure what is going on. I think I am missing something very tiny.

I really need a fresh set of eyes on this to let me know what I did wrong or I am missing. Thank you so much for you time.

Here is my code in my html:

```
<div id="memWrap">
     <script id="m-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
          <div class='row'> 
                  <div class='two columns'> 
                       <h2> {{cells.B}}</h2> 
                       <p>Years attended: {{cells.E}} </p>
                  </div> 
                  <div class='seven columns'> 
                       <div class='four columns'> 
                              <p>{{cells.F}} </p>
                       </div>
                       <div class='four columns'>
                               <div class='row'>
                                     <div class='two columns'>
                                           <img src='{{cells.K}}' />
                                     </div>
                                     <div class='two columns'>
                                           <img src='{{cells.M}}' />
                                     </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class='row'>
                                     <div class='two columns'>
                                           <img src='{{cells.L}}' />
                                     </div>
                                     <div class='two columns'>
                                           <img src='{{cells.N}}' />
                                     </div>
                               </div>
                      </div>
                 </div>
          </div>
    </script>
</div>
<script type="application/javascript">
       // Define spreadsheet URL.
        var mySpreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17kW3grN5rrKMnaA-5oS77EZr2Jmfu43oSPXBZKd8BAw/edit#gid=0';


        // Compile the Handlebars template for memories.
        var MMTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#m-template').html());

        // Load sheet for memories.
        $('#memWrap').sheetrock({
            url: mySpreadsheet,
            query: "select B,E,F,K,L,M,N",
            rowHandler: MMTemplate
        });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but you need to use `cells.name` or `cells.email` instead of  `cells.B` or `cells.C`

Another option is to go by the array number, such as `{{cellsArray.[0]}}`.

**Edit:** Also, no column N exists, so you'd just want `query: "select B,E,F,K,L,M"`

Comment: Thank you Steve for the input. I decided to use labels in my sheetrock functions for my cells which made it easier to get the data out. Sorry about not updating this post to reflect this.